# ¿Cómo puedo guardar la imagen de una huella digital en SQL Server y Java?

Tags: sql-server, netbeans

Estoy realizando una aplicación que tiene que  guardar y verificar la persona que ingreso su huella, por el momento solo muestra la imagen de la huella desde el lector pero no se como guardar la imagen en la base de datos que tengo en sql server, el lector que estoy usando es el de digitalPersona.

El método que tengo para generar la imagen de mi huella es el siguiente:

```
public void DibujarHuella(Image image){
  lblHuella.setIcon(
    new ImageIcon(
      image.getScaledInstance(
        lblHuella.getWidth(),
        lblHuella.getHeight(),
        Image.SCALE_DEFAULT
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Y la tabla que tengo en sql es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE HUELLADIGITAL
(Id_HUELLA INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
HUELLA VARBINARY(Max) NOT NULL, 
ID_EMPLEADO_AUTO INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES EMPLEADO_AUTORIZADO,
PRIMARY KEY(ID_HUELLA))
```

Comment: Por favor, trata de detallar qué código has escrito para intentar resolver el problema (cómo obtienes la imagen, en qué tabla quieres guardarla), así como los errores y los problemas que enfrentas. "No sé cómo" es muy amplio y da a entender que no has buscado resolverlo por tu cuenta. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta.

Comment: Convertirla  en base64 y almacénala como un string en un campo en la base,  fíjate un campo bastante grande, no creo que un varchar te sirva, proba con un blob o su homólogo  en sql server